# Looking for a movie with a haunted cabin

Tags: story-identification, horror

i'm looking for a movie from the 70's or 80's or 90's.

It starts with a murder in cabin and a broken snow globe.The husband kill the wife and the son watches.

Later the cabin is visited by teens. I think the son returns with them.

The cabin looks broken from the outside but when they enter, the cabin looks intact.

Later they are attacked by zombies/demons, I don't remember well.

I remember there is a book involved, but I'm not sure.

The final scene is the main couple leaves the town but leave the book and a zombie/demon girl (face full of maggots) picks it up.

Any help identifying the movie will be great.

Comment: Could be the evil dead or one of the evil dead "homages"

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142146/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl, I couldn't find more info.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like the Evil Dead movies(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_Dead_II). The movie (I, II, and a little bit of the third) is about a group of young people who go to a cabin in the woods. The cabin had been occupied by a family prior to this new young group (unrelated, I think) and this original group all died in the cabin.

The young group find a book, the Necronomicon, and read from it, which unleashes an evil presence (which infects members of their group).

The cabin looks a little run down and is fairly nice on the inside, but that's subjective I suppose.
This:

> The final scene is the main couple leaves the town but leave the book and a zombie/demon girl picks it up.

Doesn't really fit though. At the end of Evil Dead II, the protagonist (the only one left) gets sucked through a dimensional gate into another world.

In the sequel (Army of Darkness), there's a part where they go on a quest for the book though - and there's a demon lady who *might* have picked up or touched the book.

Comment: I have seen all the evil dead movies, it's not them. I thing it was filmed around the time the first evil dead film was released.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this one is '[The Cabin in the Woods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cabin_in_the_Woods)'.

It has Murders , teens, zombies and snow-globe in it.

Comment: Can you provide some shots for the film? Or a link? Or some more details?

Comment: Checking the Wikipedia page, it seems that this film was released in 2012, while OP says they watched pre-2k. Are you accusing them of time travel?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Well it won't be the first or the last time for OPs to be mistaken in their recollections. Still, the answer could use some more effort, to make the case for that movie given the similarities.

Comment: The final scene of Cabin in the Woods is definitely NOT a zombie picking up a book.

Comment: @eshier True, when i first saw the question i didn't spot that bit.

Comment: In such cases when it is possible that the asker remembers details incorrectly, a good answer would be one which goes through each detail and shows both the corroboration and the differences.  Add that, and I'll upvote :-)

Comment: sorry, I know the movie, but the one I'm looking for its from the 80 or 90.